# Linq to Sql query with multiple aggregations

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Given a simple schema e.g. PurchaseOrders { OrderId, Total, LineItemCount }, I want to generate a simple query for some simple stats like below:

```
select sum(lineitemcount) as totalitems, sum(total) as totalsales
from purchaseorders
```

However in Linq to Sql I am struggling to get this into one query.

At the moment I have this:

```
decimal totalSales = PurchaseOrders.Sum(po => po.Total)
decimal totalItems = PurchaseOrders.Sum(po => po.LineItemcount)
```

Is there a way to do this as one query?

Comment: Update: I can get the desired effect by using the "group [po] by po.something into blah" syntax, and although this is what I need anyway, I am still curious if I can do the multiple aggregrations without a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest I can work out is to give it a fake group-by clause. It works, and outputs as you'd expect, but the generated SQL actually winds up passing in a parameter of "1" and grouping on it which is a tad suboptimal. Here's the syntax for what I've got though:

```
PurchaseOrders
    .GroupBy(po => 1)
    .Select(pogroup => new {
           TotalSales = pogroup.Sum(po => po.Total),
           TotalItems = pogroup.Sum(po => po.LineItemCount)
        });
```

Comment: Works a treat. I did have to change the sum lambdas as I believe you don't intend to refer to po as that is the group, but I got the idea and it works :-)

Comment: You're right - I mistyped it when I rewrote the query in terms of your data (I gave a similar one a few tests against a local db, translating it back to the question I mixed it up a tad). I've fixed those up just in case someone else reads later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that should work. I'm not sure of the data types so I assumed nullable integers.

```
from t in (
    from t in PurchaseOrders
    select new {
        t.LineItemCount,
        t.Total,
        Dummy = "x"
    }
)
group t by new { t.Dummy } into g
select new {
  TotalItems = (System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.LineItemCount),
  TotalSales = (System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.Total)
}
```

Comment: This works great, cheers! I have gone with the fyjham's answer as it is the generated SQL is nicer and runs slightly faster

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try Aggregate:

```
var totOrder= PurchaseOrders.Aggregate((preOrder, thisOrder)=>SumTwoOrder(preOrder, thisOrder));
var totalSales = totOrder.Total;
var totalItems=totOrder.LineItemCount;
```

This is how you can define the `SumTwoOrder` method:

```
   public PurchaseOrder SumTwoOrder(PurchaseOrder prev, PurchaseOrder thisOrder)
  {
    return new PurchaseORder(prev.Total+thisOrder.Total, prev.LineItemCount+thisOrder.LineItemCount);
  }
```

Comment: If you pass it a function pointer like that then it's using it as an IEnumerable, which means all the aggregation will happen in C# and not in the database.

Comment: Yea, I have a lot of data so I really need SQL to do the aggregating for me. Nice idea, and I can actually use this method for other parts of my data so thanks :-)