# Multiple Counts within a single query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I want a list of counts for some of my data (count the number of open.closed tasks etc), I want to get all counts inside *1 query*, so I am not sure what I do with my linq statement below...

_*user* is an object that returns info about the current loggedon user

_*repo* is am object that returns an IQueryable of whichever table I want to select

```
       var counters = (from task in _repo.All<InstructionTask>()
                        where task.AssignedToCompanyID == _user.CompanyID || task.CompanyID == _user.CompanyID
                        join instructions in _repo.GetAllMyInstructions(_user) on task.InstructionID equals
                            instructions.InstructionID
                        group new {task, instructions}
                            by new
                                   {
                                       task
                                   }
                        into g
                        select new
                                   {
                                       TotalEveryone = g.Count(),
                                       TotalMine = g.Count(),
                                       TotalOpen = g.Count(x => x.task.IsOpen),
                                       TotalClosed = g.Count(c => !c.task.IsOpen)
                                   }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Do I convert my object to single or default? The exception I am getting is, *this sequence contains more than one element*

Note: I want **overall stats**, not for each task, but for **all** tasks - not sure how to get that?

Comment: Try [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Of TSource) Method (IEnumerable(Of TSource))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

Comment: Your grope by will yield a group per task so why are you grouping at all?

Comment: @RuneFS - how would I rewrite this to not group to get what I want?

Comment: I don't know what you want grouping by task and your single in the end confuses me. I can't see why you would group in the first place and the query looks like it's going to yield more than one result most of the time which will throw when you're using SingleOrDefault. Write some sample input and expected output and that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dump everything into a single group, and use a regular `Single`. I am not sure if LINQ-to-SQL would be able to translate it correctly, but it's definitely worth a try.

```
var counters = (from task in _repo.All<InstructionTask>()
    where task.AssignedToCompanyID == _user.CompanyID || task.CompanyID == _user.CompanyID
    join instructions in _repo.GetAllMyInstructions(_user) on task.InstructionID == instructions.InstructionID
    group task by 1 /* <<=== All tasks go into one group */ into g select new {
        TotalEveryone = task.Count(),
        TotalMine = task.Count(), // <<=== You probably need a condition here
        TotalOpen = task.Count(x => x.task.IsOpen),
        TotalClosed = task.Count(c => !c.task.IsOpen)

    }).Single();
```

Comment: I dont want a count for each task, I want overall stats, sorry my group statement is probably wrong too, can you advise?

Comment: This looks like it works, will need to test this out and try to understand your code though, never seen group task by 1 before???

Comment: @Haroon It's a little trick that I learned from [an earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880634/linq-to-sql-query-with-multiple-aggregations). `1` is not essential here - you could replace it with any number; all that's needed it to put all records into a single group.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx)

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

You need to use `FirstOrDefault`. `SingleOrDefault is` designed for collections that contains exactly 1 element (or none).